# Access node app on digital ocean - This site can't be reached

Tags: node.js, git, hosting, digital-ocean

I am unable to access my digital ocean node js app. I've already SSH'ed in, cloned my Node app from Git, npm installed, and successfully started the app on the droplet, yet I get error

> This site can't be reached

[image]

Digital Ocean docs say you can access your publicly facing website simply by going to `<your website's ip>:<port>`:

[image]

I did this by going to `67.205.185.63:9000/` (my app is running on port 9000 as you can see):

> root@nodejs-512mb-nyc1-01:~/demos# npm start
>
> live-demos@1.0.0 start /root/demos
>
> node app.js
>
> Demos is listening on port 9000

How else should I be accessing my node app?

---

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

...

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Demos is listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande added above

Comment: hmmm, did you setup any firewall?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande No I did not.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande the app code I just posted? you can access it from your browser? Did you create a distribution or a one-click app?

Comment: Yes, nothing weird about the code, a normal express server. You only installed git & node and nothing else?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Some Digital Ocean droplets (mainly [one-click apps](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/one-click-apps/)) come with ufw firewall installed and by default all ports except for 22, 80, and 443 are blocked.

To check if ufw is installed and which ports are blocked/open do:

`sudo ufw status`

**Output:**

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

To allow traffic on port 9000 do:

```
sudo ufw allow 9000/tcp
```

Comment: WOW!!! Wish that was in the documentation. Just spent about 6 hours banging my head against the wall. THANK YOU! Worked perfectly!

Comment: THANK YOU!! Saved my hours of head banging

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue too

Comment: Damn!!!!....Damn!!!!......Damn!!!!.......THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU!

Comment: Thats very weird.. It should be written all over the place in these articles of how to configure the express server.. None of the official articles or blog ones noted that. It worked for me as well after trying to reconfigure everything bazilion times

Answer (score 0):

Add the 9000 port by writing following command

```
sudo ufw allow 9000
```