# What else is required to access a node app from outside a Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: node.js, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

We have set up a node server which runs on port 5000.

In a [newly created droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-your-first-digitalocean-droplet), we have [installed and started nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04). To access the node app, we have changed the default port from 80 to 5000 in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {
        listen 5000 default_server;
        listen [::]:5000 default_server;
```

[`ufw` is enabled](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1514714)

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Also [the port is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991262/2404470)

```
sudo ufw allow 5000/tcp
```

Also, tried this way too:

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
```

As confirmed with `sudo ufw status`

[image: sudo ufw status]

netstat -ntlp

[image: netstat -ntlp]

Also [the app is configured to listen on the public interface](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nodejs-express-app-can-t-serve-on-port-5000)

```
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', server.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

However, not even the default port was responding. Hence, we reverted to 80 as the default port.

What else is required to access node app outside of the droplet?

Comment: what is the output of `iptables -S`  and `netstat -plant` when you run on port 5000?

Comment: And the output of `netstat -ntlp` ?

Comment: Why did you change nginx to listen on port 5000? Isn't that where you node app is listening on? You should let nginx serve traffic on port 80 and proxy/forward that traffic to port 5000 (where you node app picks it up).

Comment: @Oliver added the output for reference purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to NodeJS and NGINX, we'll want to configure NGINX to listen on port `80`, though we'll want to use `proxy_pass` to pass the request from the web server (NGINX) to the NodeJS application on the port that the application is running on. This will allow us to keep the port out of the URL.

With the current configuration, NGINX would be listening on port `5000` which would prevent the application from being able to listen in on the same port (or vice versa).

There is an excellent guide that covers setting up NodeJS + NGINX -- this specific part is the most important:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04#set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-server

The above covers how we'd go about setting up the Server Block :-)